# Multiple graphs on one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My problem is that I have my data stored in several .txt files. I wish to read the file (this part is complete), then plot the data from the file.

#### Question

For each file I have read X and Y into an array, A, as columns (e.g. for file 1 A[0,:] = X and A[1,:] = Y and so on). I end up with an array and I would like to plot all my graphs as one figure... My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

while k in range(0,3):
    plt.plot(A[k,:],A[k+1,:])
    plt.hold()
    k = k + 2

plt.show()
```

Maximum value of k = 3, since I do it for only two files. The result I got is plot(A[0,:],A[1,:]), and when I close it plot(A[2,:],A[3,:]) pops up.

Can anyone help me with this? Is there any way to "hold" that graph and show at the end with all plots? I would also like to give them different colours with a legend if it's possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `for` and `range` with step.

```
for k in range(0,4,2):
    plt.plot(A[k,:], A[k+1,:],label = 'File {}'.format(k/2 + 1))
    plt.hold()
plt.legend()
```